# How edit data from form django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm learning Django Framework, and I have a question.  To help you understand I will try and explain using the example below:

Suppose that we have some table in db as is:

```
CREATE TABLE names (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100));
```

And I have the form in **Django Admin** as is:

```
<form>
    <textarea name="names"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="sbt" value="Submit">
</form>
```

User entered something in the input `names` in the form and submitted it.  Then a script catches this data and splits it into an array (`str.split("\n")`) and in cycle adding to table names!

And I many quetion:

1. How i can add form to Django Admin?
2. How i can catch form data and add this data to somethink table in database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must create a django model.

Put this code in `models.py`.

```
class Names(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

Then you must create the admin model.

Put this code in `admin.py`.

```
class NamesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    # whatever you want in your admin panel like filter, search and ...

admin.site.register(Names, NamesAdmin)
```

I think it meet your request. And for split the names you can override save model method and split the names in there. But if you want to have an extra form, you can easily create a django model form.

Put the code somewhere like `admin.py`, `views.py` or `forms.py`

```
class NamesForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Names
```

That's your model and form. So, if your want to add the form to django admin panel you must create a view for it in django admin. For do this create a view as common.

Put the code in your `admin.py` or `views.py`.

```
def spliter(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = NamesForm(req.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for name in form.cleaned_data['names'].split(' '):
                Names(name = name).save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('') # wherever you want to redirect
        return render(req, 'names.html', {'form': form})
    return render(req, 'names.html', {'form': NamesForm()})
```

Be aware you must create the `names.html` and put the below code in you html page.

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- /admin/names/spliter/ is your url in admin panel (you can change it whatever you want) -->
    <form action="/admin/names/spliter/" method="post" >{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="'Send'" >
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is your view and your can use it everywhere. But if you want only the admin have permission to see this page you must add this method too your `NamesAdmin` class.

```
def get_urls(self):
    return patterns(
        '',
        (r'^spliter/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(spliter)) # spliter is your view
    ) + super(NamesAdmin, self).get_urls()
```

That's It. I hope this can help you.